# Stopping a PowerShell command

Tags: powershell

How do I stop a PowerShell command when it has started executing?

E.g. How do I stop a command like this

```
Select-String -Path c:\*.* "Cat"
```

without having to kill my PowerShell terminal?

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Break</kbd> does not work.

Comment: Tried CTRL+Break? Not ctrl+c, not just break, but ctrl+break? I always tend to mash all those combinations when I see a terminal not closing infront of me.

Comment: I'm confused why anyone downvoted this. I wish this site required a comment to downvote. Drive-by downvotes are not useful to anyone.

Comment: No key combination I can come up with will stop the command.

Comment: Mind-boggling that you cannot really interrupt/stop a command. I ran `ping -t <ip>` in PowerShell and now I cannot stop it, without terminating PowerShell itself.

Answer (score 3):

While the script runs type Ctrl+Break.